# How to filter output data JSON foreach with php?

Tags: php, json, loops, filtering

I have the following data :

```
$data = '
[{"kode":"AX5","harga":"6200","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX10","harga":"11250","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX25","harga":"25750","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX50","harga":"50800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX100","harga":"100600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B25","harga":"25500","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B50","harga":"49800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B100","harga":"99100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B150","harga":"147850","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B200","harga":"196600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"C5","harga":"4750","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C10","harga":"9775","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C20","harga":"19850","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C50","harga":"50100","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C100","harga":"100050","status":"2"},
{"kode":"E5","harga":"5100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E10","harga":"10425","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E25","harga":"25350","status":"1"}]'
```

The following code-snippet returns all values from `kode`:

```
$hasil = json_decode($data);
foreach ($hasil as $hasilz) {
    echo $hasilz->kode . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I want to filter code and only show the following values (`AX` and `C`):

```
AX5 AX10 AX25 AX50 AX100 
C5 C10 C20 C50 C100
```

Any body can help me filter `$hasilz->kode` with `foreach` ?

Comment: What you want, I mean what is you intended output? Currently your output is `AX5 AX10 AX25 AX50 AX100 B25 B50 B100 B150 B200 C5 C10 C20 C50 C100 E5 E10 E25` Do you want only Ax and C?

Comment: Yes, AX and C only

Comment: Check the solution you just need to see the string functions available in php.

Comment: Looking at comments, the question got more clear, added that to the question to clearify what OP's expected result is.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Use **substr()** method to check the content of the string if you know the string pattern and length of the string.

```
foreach ($hasil as $hasilz) {
  if(substr($hasilz->kode,0,2)=="AX"||substr($hasilz->kode,0,1)=="C"){
     echo $hasilz->kode . PHP_EOL; 
  }
}
```

You can also use `$hasilz->kode[0]=='A' and $hasilz->kode[0]=='C'` to check the first character.

You can also use `strstr()` — Find the first occurrence of a string

Comment: In the future I have more data 'kode'
This code will show me data 'kode' AXX or AXB or CAB or CB
it's possible filter AX[number] and C[number] only ?

Comment: ok if so then use `substr($hasilz->kode,0,1)=="A"||substr($hasilz->kode,0,1)=="C"` to check only the first character because its does not matter other character.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/WZOc83/1), below one is for AX[number] and C[number].

```
foreach(json_decode($data) as $hasilz) 
{
    if(preg_match("/^(AX|C)\d+$/",$hasilz->kode)) 
            echo $hasilz->kode . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Script**

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php
$data = '
[{"kode":"AX5","harga":"6200","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX10","harga":"11250","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX25","harga":"25750","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX50","harga":"50800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX100","harga":"100600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B25","harga":"25500","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B50","harga":"49800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B100","harga":"99100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B150","harga":"147850","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B200","harga":"196600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"C5","harga":"4750","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C10","harga":"9775","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C20","harga":"19850","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C50","harga":"50100","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C100","harga":"100050","status":"2"},
{"kode":"E5","harga":"5100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E10","harga":"10425","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E25","harga":"25350","status":"1"}, 
{"kode":"CXX25","harga":"25350","status":"1"}]';

foreach(json_decode($data) as $hasilz) 
{
    if(preg_match("/^(AX|C)\d+$/",$hasilz->kode)) 
            echo $hasilz->kode . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ php test.php
AX5
AX10
AX25
AX50
AX100
C5
C10
C20
C50
C100
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes into account a more functional paradigm using `array_filter`. Alas php does not support `some` nativly, hence one foreach could not have been avoided easily.

```
<?php
$data = '[{"kode":"AX5","harga":"6200","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX10","harga":"11250","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX25","harga":"25750","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX50","harga":"50800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"AX100","harga":"100600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B25","harga":"25500","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B50","harga":"49800","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B100","harga":"99100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B150","harga":"147850","status":"1"},
{"kode":"B200","harga":"196600","status":"1"},
{"kode":"C5","harga":"4750","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C10","harga":"9775","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C20","harga":"19850","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C50","harga":"50100","status":"2"},
{"kode":"C100","harga":"100050","status":"2"},
{"kode":"E5","harga":"5100","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E10","harga":"10425","status":"1"},
{"kode":"E25","harga":"25350","status":"1"}]';

$data = json_decode($data);

$wantedKodes = [
    'AX',
    'C',
];

$filtered = array_filter(
    $data,
    function ($object) use ($wantedKodes) {
        foreach ($wantedKodes as $kode) {
            if (strpos($object->kode, $kode) === 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
);

foreach ($filtered as $item) {
    echo "{$item->kode} \n";
}
```

Output will be:

```
AX5 
AX10 
AX25 
AX50 
AX100 
C5 
C10 
C20 
C50 
C100
```